# Invalid JSON from Stripe

Tags: ios, node.js, parse-platform, cloud, stripe-payments

Trying to use Stripe with Parse via a "Cloud Function". I made a couple of charges as of yesterday but now it stopped working (no code change)? How to a go on debugging this? Returns 200 OK in Stripe logs and JSON is valid that is sent.

Get result from Stripe module

Result: {"code":-1,"message":"Invalid JSON from Stripe."}

```
Stripe.Charges.create({
        amount: 100 * minutes, // In cents
        currency: "sek",
        customer: user.get("stripeUserId")
      },{
        success: function(httpResponse) {
          session.set("endedAt", now);
          session.set("paymentId", httpResponse["id"]);
          session.save();
          response.success();
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
          console.log("Unable to charge card");
          console.log(httpResponse);
          response.error("Unable to charge card");
        }
      });
```

Same response as this, https://www.parse.com/questions/invalid-json-from-stripe

Comment: To my knowledge, this was caused by a Parse bug that Stripe made visible when the blocked urls with two slashes (parse was making requests to api.stripe.com/v1//charges (or something like that)). Stripe should have rolled back the change. Are you still seeing the error?